# degree symbol in csv file on ipad

Tags: c#, ipad, csv, safari

I am creating csv file from .NET (it has utf8 encoding). It looks great from PCs, but our requirement is that file should be accessible from the iPad browser. Somehow that file does not open from iPad. If I remove degree symbols, it works. any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: What message/error do you get when you try to open it on the iPad?

Comment: Can you dig up any error messages? What do you mean it "does not open"? It crashes, hangs, what?

Comment: When you open the file on the IPad do you make sure the encoding is known to the application?  The default encoding is likely different on an iPad for many reasons.

Comment: It just hangs. Since I open it in separate window, all I see is a blank window.

Comment: @Ramhound: No. I don't specify separate encoding for iPad. I tried Encoding.Default, but that didn't work.

Comment: @user1760153 - What encoding exactly is the default encoding on an IPad?  I suggest you determine that and change the encoding .NET uses to create the file.